# Make Image Appear after X Seconds Javascript (web design)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically, I have images of bubbles that are animated to go from the bottom to the top of an image. Then they rise up to the image after different amounts of time with different widths. However, when they're at the bottom, they're all visible in a straight line. How do I make it so that they're only visible when they start rising into the image.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=
    , initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="thing.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bubbles" id="bubbles">
    <img src="./Images/bubble copy.png" alt="">
    <img src="./Images/bubble copy.png" alt="">
    <img src="./Images/bubble copy.png" alt="">
    <img src="./Images/bubble copy.png" alt="">
    <img src="./Images/bubble copy.png" alt="">
    <img src="./Images/bubble copy.png" alt="">
    <img src="./Images/bubble copy.png" alt="">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```html
.bubbles img {
  width: 50px;
  animation: bubble 7s linear infinite;
}
.bubbles {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -70px;
}

@keyframes bubble {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-80vh);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.bubbles img:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 7.5s;
  width: 25px;
}
.bubbles img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
.bubbles img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
  width: 65px;
}
.bubbles img:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.bubbles img:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 4.5s;
}
.bubbles img:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.bubbles img:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
  width: 25px;
}
```

Comment: seems to already do what you are asking, https://jsfiddle.net/tnc73hr4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a setTimeout and diffrent times.
This is probably not the best solution but it can work.

```
<img id=img src="img.png">
<script>
  let img = document.getElementById('img')
  let time = 1000 // time in milliseconds
  img.hidden = true // set img to hidden on load
  setTimeout(()=> {
    img.hidden = false // after timeout show img
  }, time)
</script>
```

Comment: Somehow, setting hidden to false didn't work in my case. It might be due to the fact that I'm not hiding imgs but svgs though. I used display='none' and img.style.display = 'inline' in the script to fix it. Of course this depends on knowing which "display" style is the right one, so I don't really like this solution.